# Check if there is a dictionary inside a list comprehension

Tags: python, list, dictionary

How could i check if there is a dict inside a list comprehension?

I'm trying like this:

```
print dict in [company["attribute"] for company in dictionary["companies"]]
```

Which is returning False, when it should return True.

Thanks.

Comment: To check if there is a particular dictionary or just that the list contains a dictionary?

Comment: What does it matter how the list got created?

Comment: Just if there is a dictionary @MosesKoledoye

Answer (score 5):

`dict` is a `class` so you are asking is this class which creates dictionaries in the `list`? What you really want to know is whether an instance created by `dict` is in the `list`. You can use [**`isinstance`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) to compare.

You said you check whether a dictionary is in a list comprehension, but actually your code creates a `list` (using a list comprehension), then checks if `dict` is in the `list`. You throw away the list afterwards. This is inefficient as you build a whole list even if you just want to check the first few items in it until you find a match.

You could use [**`any`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) with [**`isinstance`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
print any(isinstance(company["attribute"], dict)
          for company in dictionary["companies"])
```

My code uses a generator expression which is a generalisation of a comprehension:

```
g = (isinstance(company["attribute"], dict)
     for company in dictionary["companies"])
```

`g` hasn't actually been evaluated yet so none of the attributes have been checked to see whether they are an instance of a `dict`. It's only when the generator is consumed, or materialised, that it will start to evaluate and yield results.

`g` as a generator can be passed to any function which takes a sequence of values:

```
print any(g)
```

The `any` function will iterate through the values the generator yields. `any` is looking for any value which evaluates to `True`, and will stop at the first value. This means the generator is only evaluated as many times as is needed, and is an efficient way of searching sequentially.

Similarly, `next` can be used with the generator to find the next value matching some criteria. So if you wanted the actual dictionary, you can say:

```
attribute = next(company["attribute"]
                 for company in dictionary["companies"]
                 if isinstance(company["attribute"], dict))
```

Comment: This answer should be "You could use **`isinstance`** (and also `any`)"

Answer (score 2):

`print any(map(lambda x: isinstance(x, dict), [company... ]))` should work.

Comment: `[company... ]` is a shortcut for whatever list comprehension you are using.  

`lambda x: isinstance(x, dict)` is a function that returns `True` if the argument is a `dict` object and `False` if it's something else.  

`map(lambda ..., [company ...])` transforms the `[company... ]` list into a list with results of calling the `lambda ...` function on its elements, so something like `[True, False, False, ...` for a list that had a `dict` as its first element followed by two non-dicts.  

`any(iterable)` returns `True` iff any element of `iterable` is truthy.